# Can't get test through the end with protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have simple test doing login and trying to check if it's success:

```
describe('My Angular App', function () {

  describe('visiting the main homepage', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
      browser.get('/');
      element(By.id("siteLogin")).click();
    });

    it('should login successfully', function() {

      element(By.name("login_username")).sendKeys("test@email.com");
      element(By.name("login_password")).sendKeys("testpass");

      element(By.id("formLoginButton")).click().then(function() {

        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
          expect(url).toContain("profile");
        });

      });

    });

  });

});
```

It goes well until that last part where I'm checking URL, and in **Selenium Server** I get:

```
INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);

  try {
    if (window.getAngularTestability) {
      window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
      return;
    }
    if (!window.angular) {
      throw new Error('angular could not be found on the window');
    }
    if (angular.getTestability) {
      angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
    } else {
      if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
        throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
           ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
      }
      angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
          notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err.message);
  }
}).apply(this, arguments); }
catch(e) { throw (e instanceof Error) ? e : new Error(e); }, [body]])
```

and also I get:

```
Failures:
1) My Angular App visiting the main homepage should login successfully
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

My **protractor-conf.js**:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/Mysite',

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox' // muste use firefox because I can't get .click() to work in Chrome
  },

  specs: [
    'spec-e2e/*.js'
  ],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

I appreciate any help on this one.
Thanks

Comment: Print all the log stacktrace and the html to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a non-Angular page opened after a click. If this is the case, you need to t*urn the synchronization between Protractor and Angular off*:

```
afterEach(function () {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});

it('should login successfully', function() {
  element(By.name("login_username")).sendKeys("test@email.com");
  element(By.name("login_password")).sendKeys("testpass");

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  element(By.id("formLoginButton")).click().then(function() {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("profile");
  });
});
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly resolve the promise returned by `getCurrentUrl` and can let the `expect()` do that for you implicitly.

You may also need to [wait for the URL to change](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions):

```
var urlChanged = function(desiredUrl) {
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    return url == desiredUrl;
  });
};

browser.wait(urlChanged("my desired url"), 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I still get that async error... And after click, it's redirected to Angular page too, tried to change `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to true but still the same...